# Xpath to find an element present inside two different self closing tags

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

My correct XML is:

```
<xml>
   <astart/>
     <a>XXX</a>
      <bstart/>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y>
        <b>AAA</b>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y>
      <bend/>
    <aend/>
    <astart/>
      <bstart/>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y>
        <b>BBB</b>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y>
      <bend/>
    <aend/>
</xml>
```

Incorrect XML example but the scenario may be anything incorrect:

```
    <xml>
      <astart/>
     <a>XXX</a>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y>
      
        <b>AAA</b>
      
    <aend/>
    <astart/>
      <bend/>
        <b>BBB</b>
       <x>..</x>
       <y>..</y> 
    <aend/>
   </xml>
```

I want to find "`<b>`" tag present with in "`<astart/>...<bstart/>..<b>..</b>... <bend/>...<aend/>`". If not matches this pattern needs Xpath to identify.

I tried the code `//b[preceding-sibling::astart[1][not(preceding-sibling::bstart[1])]][following-sibling::aend[1][not(following-sibling::bend[1])]]` but it was not working for the incorrect pattern. Note: All tags are siblings, not parent or ancestors also  and  tags are optional.

Comment: *"All tags are siblings..."* Then what you have is not XML. A well-formed XML document must have a single root element. It's also not clear what exactly you are testing for when there are multiple start-end sequences. What if one of them has the `b` element where you expect it and the other one does not?

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath 3.1 it sounds as if the following using the `<<` and `>>` operators together with `for-each-pair` could help:

```
let $root := /,
    $astarts := //astart,
    $aends := //aend
return
    for-each-pair(
      $astarts, 
      $aends, 
      function($s, $e) {
        let $bstarts := $root//bstart[. >> $s and . << $e],
            $bends := $root//bend[. >> $s and . << $e]
        return
            for-each-pair(
              $bstarts, 
              $bends, 
              function($s, $e) {
                $root//b[. >> $s and . << $e]
              }
            )
      }
    )
```

XQuery's windowing feature seems also a good fit:

```
for tumbling window $w in /xml/*
start $s when $s instance of element(astart)
end $e when $e instance of element(aend)
return
  for tumbling window $w in $w
  start $s when $s instance of element(bstart)
  end $e when $e instance of element(bend)
  return $w[self::b]
```

Or in XSLT 2/3 you could nest `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with`, the following sample tries to use only XSLT 2 (but I haven't checked that exactly):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="start-suffix" as="xs:string" select="'start'"/>
  <xsl:param name="end-suffix" as="xs:string" select="'end'"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:wrapped-elements" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="container" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="outer-wrapper" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="inner-wrapper" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="wrapped" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$container/*" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = concat($outer-wrapper, $start-suffix)]">
      <xsl:if test="self::*[local-name() = concat($outer-wrapper, $start-suffix)]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)" group-ending-with="*[local-name() = concat($outer-wrapper, $end-suffix)]">
          <xsl:if test="current-group()[last()][self::*[local-name() = concat($outer-wrapper, $end-suffix)]]">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="subsequence(current-group(), 1, count(current-group()) - 1)" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = concat($inner-wrapper, $start-suffix)]">
              <xsl:if test="self::*[local-name() = concat($inner-wrapper, $start-suffix)]">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)" group-ending-with="*[local-name() = concat($inner-wrapper, $end-suffix)]">
                  <xsl:if test="current-group()[last()][self::*[local-name() = concat($inner-wrapper, $end-suffix)]]">
                    <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[self::*[local-name() = $wrapped]]"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrapped-elements(., 'a', 'b', 'b')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want the code using xpath 2.0. Any possibility?

Comment: As far as I remember, `<<` and `>>` exist since XPath 2.0; XSLT since 2.0 has `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` for sure. XQuery windowing was introduced in 3.0, I think. Pure XPath 2 might be hard, wait for the purists light Dimitre to throw in their skills.

Comment: @BWin, I tried to give you an example for an XSLT 2.0 function using nested `for-each-group group-starting/ending-with`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to detect incorrectly nested pairs of `astart`/`aend` or `bstart`/`bend`, but I am not sure because you speak only about the `b` element.

Anyway, the following XSLT 1.0 stylesheet finds the first incorrectly nested pair and reports it, for your second example, as `<bend number="1" expected="a"/>`, which means that the first `bend` element is wrong, since an `aend` was expected.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="stack"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="astart | bstart">
    <xsl:param name="stack"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="concat(substring(name(current()),1,1),' ',$stack)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="aend | bend">
    <xsl:param name="stack"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring-before($stack,' ') = substring(name(current()),1,1)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
          <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="substring-after($stack,' ')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="number">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())]) + 1"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="expected">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($stack,' ')"/>
            <xsl:text>end</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="stack"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="$stack"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your first (correct) example, this stylesheet outputs nothing.